# Serve JSON on a Specific Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I am trying to create a simple API by creating a route that responds with JSON at the path `/json`

and Serve the object `{"message": "Hello json"}` as a response, in JSON format, to GET requests to the `/json` route.

```js
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.get("/json", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: "Hello json"
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Here is my code, but its giving me a "not found" error.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to set a port, try this code, it should work.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/json', (req, res) => {
  res.json({"message": "Hello json"})
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```